# Группировка строк по шаблону (MySQL, СУБД, MS Access)

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ms-access

В таблице более 200тыс строк (test и ее копия test1).
В графе 'title' неуникальные записи в формате str.
Необходимо создать запрос, выдающий таблицу со сгруппированными строками по графе 'title' где есть вхождение содержимого 'title' каждой строки. Т.е.:

```
SELECT test1.title, count(test1.title) as count
FROM
test
JOIN
#из копии таблицы выбираем каждую строку и ищем строки в которых есть
#совпадения с искомым значением
test1
ON test.title LIKE CONCAT('%',test1.title,'%')
#группируем результаты, идет подсчет совпадений
GROUP BY test1.title
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Запрос запускается, но не выполняется - на 600 сек завершается автоматически.

Comment: Может попробовать через полнотекстовый поиск?

Comment: Ну как бы да, стоит попробовать полнотекстовый, не забыв построить для него fulltext индекс

Comment: А как? ) `SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('*test.title*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`